# Git svn fetch retrieving only one revision at a time

Tags: svn, git, revision, fetch, head

I'm using Git-1.6.5.1-preview20091022.exe.

I've cloned a SubVersion repository using:

```
git svn clone -s https://xxxxx:8443/svn/project/SubProjectA
```

The SubProjectA has the standard layout (trunk, branches, tags).
SubProjectA is a copy of another project. It has only 60 revisions if it own.
After the command, a folder is created with the name SubProjectA and has only remotes/trunk as the branch. Even the master branch does not exists.

I then have to run

```
git svn fetch
```

multiple times to get all revisions from the SubVersion. Every time the fetch command is ran, it fetches only one revision at a time.

I've tried:

```
git svn fetch -r2400:HEAD
git svn fetch -r2400:2450
```

without success (SubProjectA is copied at revision 2390, there are one branch of SubProjectA created at revision 2420, the latest revision is 2450).

What did I do that caused the fetch command to fetch only one revision at a time?
How do I tell fetch to get all revisions?

Answer (score 4):

To do a full update, use

```
git svn rebase
```

You should read [this article](http://flavio.castelli.name/howto_use_git_with_svn) about working using `svn-git`.

Comment: Git still only fetches some revisions, not all. I've just tried git svn rebase, and it fetches 3 revisions. When I run git svn rebase again, the remaining 2 revisions are fetched.

Comment: That's because you have run `git svn fetch` before doing `git svn rebase`. I suggest you start again with blank repo, and follow steps in the article I give above.

Comment: Did this issue ever get resolved?  I am struggling with this issue now and I can't do a "git svn rebase" right after the "git svn init" because I get an error "Fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD'"  I googled the error and the fix is to run "git svn fetch"!  :-P  Any further clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Patrick, it's better you create a new question, and include the detail about your repository state.